# Found duplicate dependency key

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a TCC but I went to emulate from Android Studio or at Expo it's giving this error.

Android Bundling Failed 25ms
resolveDependencies: duplicate dependency key found 'undefined' in C:\Users\Iury\Desktop\ranngo2\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/roBca.png

Comment: Please post the code as text in your question, not an image.